# Android webView evaluateJavaScript executes undefined function

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, onkeydown

I'm developing an Android application that contains a WebView.
I am trying to override onKeyDown activity's method.

I want to call a javascript method everytime phone's backButton is pressed and if the method is undefined I want to execute other native instruction (I want to close the activity).

This is the sense: natively I do this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (true) {
                    webView.evaluateJavascript(  "try{pageGoBack();}" +
                                                        "catch{window.JSInterface.noBackFunction();}",null);
                    webView.clearCache(true);
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And for **every** jsp server side I want to implement something like this:

```
<script>
        function pageGoBack() {
                       ---do something to go back---
                }
        }
</script>
...
```

This method had to have the same name "pageGoBack" for every jsp but can have different inner code

That's the fact: before I load one of that jsp with the `pageGoBack` method everything works (error 'undefined' is catched and JSInterface method is executed).

When I load one of that page the method "remains in cache (???)" and it is always executed (also in those page without it) .

(Look that I also added `webView.clearCache(true);` but the problem remains)

Thank you -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

That was not a problem of Android's WebView or cache. That's a problem of javascript.
When a function is defined in  as "global" it assumes the global scope when it is evaluated for the first time. So when I visited the .jsp which contains pageGoBack() for the first time the function became globally visible.

Solution for my case:

I have lots of jsp with graphic component like this ◄ that means "go back to the previous page". I needed to associate the -jquery button tap function of the current page- to the Android back button. 
So I:

- Created an empty css class .empty-class-for-back-button
- Gave this class to all those ◄ component
- Made a global js function like this

```
function pageGoBack() { 
 var backBtn = $('.empty-class-for-back-button');
 if (backBtn.length > 0){
  backBtn.tap();
 }
 else{
  throw "css class not found";
 }
}
```

- Android code is the same I've written in the question

Exception is now thrown correctly if there is no ◄ element in the current page.

Hope this can be helpful to somebody.